# Passing data to dynamic component from parent component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to set data of dynamic component from the parent component

For example : 
Parent Component :

```
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="(component, index) in components">
      <component :is="component" :key="index"></component>
  </template>
  <button @click="add()">Add Component</button>
</div>
```

Dynamic Component :

```
 let dynamicComponent = {
  template: `
    <p>Welcome {{ msg }}!</p>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'home'
    }
  },
}

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    components: [
      dynamicComponent
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    add () {
      this.components.push(dynamicComponent);
    },
  }
});
```

I want to set the data of the dynamic component from the parent component when the new dynamic component is added.

In this case, the **msg** property of dynamicComponent from the parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like  `props:['msg']` in component

```js
let dynamicComponent = {
  template: `
    <p>Welcome {{ msg2 }}, {{ msg }}!</p>
  `,
  props:['msg'],
  data () {
    return {
      msg2: 'component message'
    }
  },
}

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    components: [
      dynamicComponent
    ],
    parentMsg:'parent message'
  },

  methods: {
    add () {
      this.components.push(dynamicComponent);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="(component, index) in components">
      <component :msg="parentMsg" :is="component" :key="index"></component>
  </template>
  <button @click="add()">Add Component</button>
  <input type="text" v-model="parentMsg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you could do this:

Parent template:

```
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="(component, index) in components">
      // Add :msg to pass 'msg' to child component.
      <component :is="component" :key="index" :msg="msg"></component>
  </template>
  <button @click="add()">Add Component</button>
</div>
```

Js:

```
let dynamicComponent = {
   props: ['msg'], //<-- Specify the child will receive a prop 'msg'
   template: `<p>Welcome {{ msg }}!</p>`
}

const App = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      components: [
         dynamicComponent
      ],
      msg: 'Hello' //<-- Set the value of 'msg'
   },

   methods: {
      add() {
         this.components.push(dynamicComponent);
      },
   }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/willabbott/pen/QWwQmVd)